# Location of Glassfish 4 on Eclipse ee using windows 10

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I have downloaded Glassfish 4 from Eclipse ee, now i'm trying to create a new server, it asks me the glassfish location and the java location, i can't manage to find the glassfish location, and for java i put the folder where the jdk is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you downloaded but as far as I can see there is no Eclipse package on http://eclipse.org which includes the Glassfish Server.

So I assume you have installed the [Glassfish Tools for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools) for your current Eclipse. If not, you should do this first.

You can download the Glassfish Server package manually here: https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Extract the ZIP file where you like and use this folder as your Glassfish location.

Answer (score 2):

- **GlassFish location**: the domain folder of your Glassfish (D:\glassfish-4.1.1-web\glassfish4\glassfish\domain\domain1), or maybe just the install folder (D:\glassfish-4.1.1-web\glassfish4\glassfish).
- **Java location**: your JDK location (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91)